# SQL Query to merge two tables with different timestamp as index

Tags: mysql, sql, put

I am not sure if my question will work with a sql query.

I have the two following Mysql tables:

**Table a:**
The table get every 20 second a new Value

```
a.Time                  a.Value
2015-05-14 07:36:36     49
2015-05-14 07:36:56     49
2015-05-14 07:37:16     49
2015-05-14 07:37:36     49
2015-05-14 07:37:56     50
2015-05-14 07:38:16     50
2015-05-14 07:38:36     50
2015-05-14 07:38:56     49
2015-05-14 07:39:16     49
2015-05-14 07:39:36     49
2015-05-14 07:39:56     49
2015-05-14 07:40:16     50
2015-05-14 07:40:36     50
2015-05-14 07:40:56     50
2015-05-14 07:41:16     49
2015-05-14 07:41:36     49
2015-05-14 07:41:56     50
2015-05-14 07:42:16     50
2015-05-14 07:42:36     49
2015-05-14 07:42:56     49
2015-05-14 07:43:16     49
2015-05-14 07:43:36     49
2015-05-14 07:43:56     49
2015-05-14 07:44:06     49
```

**Table b**
the table get every change of the value a new record

```
b.Time              b.Value
2015-05-14 07:34:50     1500
2015-05-14 07:38:52     2000
2015-05-14 07:40:52     0
2015-05-14 07:42:31     1500
```

**The Result should like the following**

```
a.Time                  a.Value     b.Time              b.Value
2015-05-14 07:36:36     49         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:36:56     49         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:37:16     49         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:37:36     49         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:37:56     50         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:38:16     50         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:38:36     50         2015-05-14 07:34:50  1500
2015-05-14 07:38:56     49         2015-05-14 07:38:52  2000
2015-05-14 07:39:16     49         2015-05-14 07:38:52  2000
2015-05-14 07:39:36     49         2015-05-14 07:38:52  2000
2015-05-14 07:39:56     49         2015-05-14 07:38:52  2000
2015-05-14 07:40:16     50         2015-05-14 07:38:52  2000
2015-05-14 07:40:36     50         2015-05-14 07:38:52  2000
2015-05-14 07:40:56     50         2015-05-14 07:40:52  0
2015-05-14 07:41:16     49         2015-05-14 07:40:52  0
2015-05-14 07:41:36     49         2015-05-14 07:40:52  0
2015-05-14 07:41:56     50         2015-05-14 07:40:52  0
2015-05-14 07:42:16     50         2015-05-14 07:40:52  0
2015-05-14 07:42:36     49         2015-05-14 07:42:31  1500
2015-05-14 07:42:56     49         2015-05-14 07:42:31  1500
2015-05-14 07:43:16     49         2015-05-14 07:42:31  1500
2015-05-14 07:43:36     49         2015-05-14 07:42:31  1500
2015-05-14 07:43:56     49         2015-05-14 07:42:31  1500
2015-05-14 07:44:06     49         2015-05-14 07:42:31  1500
```

The time-stamps in table a should with the next smaller time-stamp from table b!

**Any idea how the query should look?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How your `table b` gets updated ? i didnt get how `b.value` generates ?

Comment: I have a system, which write the values in the database. In case of table b, value is the current wattage of a device. When the wattage change, the system will write the wattage with a timestamp in the database.

Comment: Table b: the table get every change of the value a new record...

Here what you mean by `of the value a new record`? 

The time-stamps in table a should with the next smaller time-stamp from table b!

`table a should what` ?

`next smaller time-stamp ` ?

On what basis you will match two tables? as  for example in your first record of desired result value `2015-05-14 07:36:36` of a does not match `2015-05-14 07:34:50` value of b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries with order by `TIME` and `LIMIT 1` to get one top record from B with time less than current A.Time:

```
SELECT 
a.Time,
a.Value,
(SELECT Time FROM B WHERE B.Time<=A.Time ORDER BY B.Time DESC LIMIT 1) 
     as B_Time,
(SELECT Value FROM B WHERE B.Time<=A.Time ORDER BY B.Time DESC LIMIT 1)  
     as B_Value
FROM A
ORDER BY A.Time
```